# Could Not Find Product Without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

Actually I have a Bid model with foreign keys  Product_id & User_id, I successfully assign user_id by using current_user function but I failed to assign current Product_id which opened in my Product show page. And by clicking on bid button I go to bids/new path where i just have to enter the amount but after i get This error .

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product without an ID):

**BidController**

```
class BidsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bid, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  
  def index
    @bids = Bid.all
  end

  
  def show
  end

  
  def new
    @bid = Bid.new
  end


  def edit
  end

  
  def create
    @bid = Bid.new(bid_params)
    @bid.user = current_user
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @bid.product = @product




    respond_to do |format|
      if @bid.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bid, notice: 'Bid was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bid }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @bid.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bid.update(bid_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @bid, notice: 'Bid was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @bid }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @bid.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  
  def destroy
    @bid.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bids_url, notice: 'Bid was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    
    def set_bid
      @bid = Bid.find(params[:id])
    end

    
    def bid_params
      params.require(:bid).permit(:bidamount, :user_id, :product_id)
    end


end
```

Here is My link From where I'm taking Product_id

```
<%=link_to "Bid on this Project",new_bid_path(product_id: @product), class: "btn btn-xs btn-success" %>
```

**routes.rb**

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :bids
resources :favorite_products, only: [:create, :destroy,:index]
resources :categories
resources :products
resources :users

root 'pages#home'

get 'login',  to: 'sessions#new'
get 'login',  to: 'sessions#new'
post 'login',  to: 'sessions#create'
delete 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

I'll update my code if you find it to know more.

Comment: The error indicates that `params[:product_id]` is nil where you are calling it.

Comment: i am a newby and i have a button "Place Bid" on my product show page , which  links to new_bid_path and while creating bid i want to pass the id of that product i openend before. e.g http://localhost:3000/products/1

Comment: i updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You should create the link setting the product_id `link_to new_bid_path(product_id: item.id)`

Then, at the BidController, you should define the new method

```
def new
  @bid = Bid.new(product_id: params[:product_id])
end
```

Finally, at the create action, you needn't assign the product because it's already set in the `bid_params`

---

Note: To avoid setting the user as you're doing now. Try something like `@bid = current_user.bids.create!(bid_params)`. It's a shorter way to do the same

Comment: yes i get Product id by new_bid_path(product_id: @product.id) & my URL is http://localhost:3000/bids/new?product_id=3 & I also used def new according to your method but I got the error "product must be present"

Comment: Ok. Try print `@bid` as soon as you assign the first time and paste here what you see.